# Calculate final value without using for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, cumsum

```
  upper.limit <- 15
  starting.limit <- 5
  lower.limit <- 0

  set.seed(123)

  x <- sample(-20:20)

  for(i in 1:length(x)){
        k <- starting.limit + x[i]

        k <- ifelse(k > upper.limit, upper.limit, ifelse(k < lower.limit, lower.limit,k))
        starting.limit <- k
}
```

My objective is to calculate the final value of `starting limit` at the end of the loop. The conditions are that for a given iteration, `k` cannot exceed `upper.limit` and fall below `lower.limit`.

I have written the above loop to achieve this. However, I have to do this for almost 10000 datasets. I wondered if there is a quicker way so that I can avoid a for loop

Thanks

Comment: Even with a 10k sample in x, this takes a fraction of a second.

Comment: What I meant is that I have 10000 x datasets. Not that x has 10000 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can design a function.

```
# s: starting.limit, x: the x vector, u:upper.limit, l:lower.limit
k_fun <- function(s, x, u = 15, l = 0){
  k <- s + x
  if (k > u){
    k <- u
  } else if (k < l){
    k <- l
  }
  s <- k
  return(s)
}
```

And then use `accumulate` from the `purrr` package to apply the function with the starting limit and the x vector. You can see how the number changes. The last number is the final output.

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(c(5, x), k_fun)
# [1]  5  0 11  6 15 15  0  0 10 15  9 15  8  7  3  0  3  0 15  2  2 14 15  7  4 15 15  3 15  0
# [31]  5  0  0  4 12  0  6  7  9  0  0 15
```

**Benchmark**

I used the following code to assess the performance. The `accumulate` is a little bit faster than a for loop on a vector with `400001` elements.

```
library(microbenchmark)

perf <- microbenchmark(
  m1 = {upper.limit <- 15
  starting.limit <- 5
  lower.limit <- 0
  set.seed(123)
  x <- sample(-200000:200000)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    k <- starting.limit + x[i]

    k <- ifelse(k > upper.limit, upper.limit, ifelse(k < lower.limit, lower.limit,k))
    starting.limit <- k
  }},
  m2 = {
    set.seed(123)
    x <- sample(-200000:200000)
    vec <- purrr::accumulate(c(5, x), k_fun)
    k <- tail(vec, 1)
  })

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#   m1 821.1735 879.3551 956.7404 941.1145 1019.8603 1290.800   100
#   m2 649.3444 717.5986 773.3652 768.0313  823.5749 1006.148   100
```

Comment: What I meant is that I have 10000 x datasets. Not that x has 10000 elements.

Comment: I included my solution in your microbenchmark, and seems it is faster. 
Can you please verify?

Comment: @Aramis7d I don't have time to verify your result. But I trust your result. It seems like a good way to vectorize the operation.

Comment: @KS89 It is not clear in your original question that your are talking about 10000 datasets. Because you provide a vector of `x`, I thought you were talking about the length of `x`. I guess most people also interpreted your questions the same way I did.

Comment: Oh Sorry about it. I will modify the question. But your solution works fine so thank you very much

Comment: @KS89 Thanks for your interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below with `tidyverse`

first, make `x` into a dataframe

```
x <- as.data.frame(sample(-20:20))
colnames(x) <- c("dat")
```

and then pipe like:

```
x %>%
  mutate(sm = starting.limit) %>% 
  mutate(sm = if_else(sm+lead(dat,1) > upper.limit, upper.limit
                      , if_else(sm+lead(dat,1) < lower.limit, lower.limit, sm) )) %>%
  select(sm) %>%
  filter(sm != is.na(sm)) %>%
  tail(n=1)
```

Effectively, modify the last `select`, `filter` and `tail` functions as per your need.

**Benchmark**

I was curious how this performs against the other solution, and tried to add my code to the microbenchmark already provided. Here goes

```
perf <- microbenchmark(
  m1 = {upper.limit <- 15
  starting.limit <- 5
  lower.limit <- 0
  set.seed(123)
  x <- sample(-200000:200000)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    k <- starting.limit + x[i]

    k <- ifelse(k > upper.limit, upper.limit, ifelse(k < lower.limit, lower.limit,k))
    starting.limit <- k
  }},
  m2 = {
    set.seed(123)
    x <- sample(-200000:200000)
    vec <- purrr::accumulate(c(5, x), k_fun)
    k <- tail(vec, 1)
  }, 
  m3 = {
    x <- sample(-200000:200000)
    xd <- as.data.frame(x)
    colnames(xd) <- c("dat")

    xd %>%
      mutate(sm = starting.limit) %>% 
      mutate(sm = if_else(sm+lead(dat,1) > upper.limit, upper.limit
                          , if_else(sm+lead(dat,1) < lower.limit, lower.limit, sm) )) %>%
      select(sm) %>%
      filter(sm != is.na(sm)) %>%
      tail(n=1)

  }

  )
```

output:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   m1 1223.49718 1255.69514 1272.2679 1260.9643 1272.3401 1392.0402   100
   m2  964.76948  982.96555 1007.5521  989.5366 1007.9106 1173.2754   100
   m3   68.80358   76.77386  133.0509  170.5572  177.0051  274.9299   100
```

Comment: Wait. What is the number of rows of `xd`? Notice that I change the `x` to `sample(-200000:200000)`, a lot longer than the OP's example.

Comment: i knew i was missing something. this looked too good to be true :O

Comment: Still a nice solution. My guess is it would still be reasonably fast. Thanks for sharing it.